# How to assign static IP address to Raspberry Pi Model 3+ connected via Wi-Fi?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, raspberry-pi

I recently finished setting up my Pi with Raspbian Stretch lite and configured the Wi-Fi successfully.  I was trying to assign a static IP address to it, but all I can find are tutorials for LAN not over Wi-Fi connections.  I was hoping to take the easy path and assign the IP through my router, but it doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the same way you would do it for your ethernet interface, you simply need to use the name of your wireless interface (presumably) `wlan0`.
In Raspbian stretch (lite), if you add this part to your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` you should be fine:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.99/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

Of course you need to adapt the IP-addresses to your specific setup.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, finally i decided to connect the pi directly to my router via ethernet, but now when i try to ssh into it im getting permission denied when typing the password... Any idea how to fix this without the use of a monitor?

Comment: Did you at any point activate ssh on your Raspberry Pi? Per default it is disabled.

Comment: Yes i did... now its all working smoothly.